# django class based-view infinite load more with filtered items repeating themself

Tags: jquery, django, django-class-based-views

I have a list of articles, and when I try to sort them, by date for example, I noticed something interesting (and annoying ofc) :

My pagination is limited to 10 articles maximum but whatever the date I choose (I have 10 articles in October) my load-more-button is always on.

So when I choose to sort by October, this what happen :

My articles from October 2015 are listed, I click on load more and I see the articles from January 2016.
Then if I click on load more, I see December 2015, then November **and then October again.**

And this will repeat infinitely.

For the record, I send the date in the following format : `2016-01` and it is stored the same way in the DB, `2016-01-26`.

So here is what I do in my view for the date:

```
class DateListView(BaseArticleView, ListView):
  view_url_name = 'djangocms_press:articles-date'

  def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    context = {}

    qs = super(DateListView, self).get_queryset()

    qs = qs.filter(date_realization__startswith=self.kwargs['daterealization'])
    self.object_list = qs

    context.update(self.get_context_data(**kwargs))
    context[self.context_object_name] = context['object_list']
    context['load_more_url'] = self.get_load_more_url(self.request, context)
    return self.render_to_response(context)

  def render_to_response(self, context):
    if self.request.is_ajax():
        response = self.render_to_json_response(context)
    else:
        response = super(DateListView, self).render_to_response(context)
    return response

def get_load_more_url(self, request, context):
    args = request.GET.copy()
    page_obj = context.get('page_obj', None)

    if not page_obj or not page_obj.has_next():
        return ''

    args[self.page_kwarg] = page_obj.next_page_number()
    return '?{}'.format(args.urlencode())

def render_to_json_response(self, context, **response_kwargs):
    if 'current_app' not in context:
        context['current_app'] = resolve(self.request.path).namespace

    c = RequestContext(self.request, context)

    html_items_list = render_to_string(
        'base_templates/template_press.html',
        context,
        context_instance=c)

    html_items_list = html_items_list.strip()

    json_response = {
        'html_items_list': html_items_list,
        'load_more_url': self.get_load_more_url(self.request, context),
    }

    return JsonResponse(json_response)
```

And what I do for my ajax,

On the changing select (that permit to choose the category):

```
    ajaxArticles = function(urlAjax, category) {
      var $articleList = $("#articles-list");

      $ajaxresult = $.ajax({url: urlAjax, success: function(result) {
        var content =  $('<div/>').html(result.html_items_list).contents().find("#articles-list");
        $articleList.html(content.html());

        updateLoadMoreButton(result.load_more_url);
      }});
}
```

the urlAjax is the one for the date in our example,

> url(r'^date/(?P[\w.@+-]+)/$', DateListView.as_view(), name='articles-date'),

And finally, my click on load more button :

```
    $(document).on('click', '#loadmore', function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      $this = $(this);
      var $articleList = $("#loadAppend");

      $.ajax({url: $this.attr('href'), success: function(result) {

        var content = $('<div/>').html(result.html_items_list).contents().find("#articles-list");

        content.html()
        $articleList.append(content.html());
        updateLoadMoreButton(result.load_more_url);
      }});
});
```

the $this.attr("href) is "?page=Number"

I am sooo lost. Does anyone have an idea about this problem ?
Why isn't it returning only the asked item ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it, I wasn't requesting the good url while clicking on my load-more-button, which was requesting the all url when I clicked on it.